# Why can image denoising be expressed as an energy minimization problem?

Tags: deep-learning, image-processing

I am interested in this paper by [(Ulyanov et al., 2017)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.10925), but I don't have much knowledge about image denoising. I don't understand why image denoising can be expressed as an energy minimization problem. Where does the following formula come from and what it does it mean?

> To demonstrate the power of this parametrization, we consider inverse
>   tasks such as denoising, super-resolution and inpainting. These can be
>   expressed as energy minimization problems of the type 
>   $$x^∗ = \min_x E(x; x_0) + R(x), \text{  (1)}$$
>
> where $E(x; x_0)$ is a task-dependent data term, $x_0$ the
>   noisy/low-resolution/occluded image, and $R(x)$ a regularizer.

[Ulyanov, Dmitry, Andrea Vedaldi, and Victor Lempitsky. "Deep Image Prior." arXiv preprint arXiv:1711.10925 (2017).](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.10925)

Answer (score 3):

The very short answer is that energy minimisation is a general, unifying framework for both probabilistic and deterministic machine learning models. In this very general setting, energy does not have much to do with a physical notion of energy and it is essentially a probability which has not been normalised to fall within $[0, 1]$.

---

In image denoising there is a bit of a deeper connection with physics which partly explains where this energy minimisation language comes from. Let's only consider binary images $X$ of size $n \times n$, so $X \in \{-1,1\}^N$. Suppose that we believe that the value of a pixel $s$ should depend on it's neighbours, that is the pixels which share an edge with $s$. Let $X^+_s$ and $X^−_s$ denote the number of neighbours of $s$ that take positive and negative values, then we can formalise our assumption of spatial dependency as follows
$$
P(X_s = +1|X_t, t\text{ is a neighbour of s}) = 
\frac{exp(2 \beta (X^+_s − X^−_s))}{1 + exp(2\beta(X^+_s − X^−_s))}
$$
where $\beta > 0$.  The above model also occurs in statistical physics where it is called the Ising model of ferromagnetism. The parameter $\beta$ is the inverse temperature which is very closely related to energy.

So if the noise is spatially independent, then computing the most likely configuration $X^*$ that satisfies the above relation will effectively denoise our image. Computing the most likely configuration is essential done by minimising the energy of the Ising model.

---

The equation $x^∗ = \min_x E(x; x_0) + R(x)$ is a pretty generalised formulation of the denoising problem. I'll give an example of a very common method which fits into this framework. Suppose we have an image $X$ which has been corrupted with additive Gaussian noise. That is we have
$$
Y = X + \epsilon, \text{ where } \epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma)
$$
where $Y$ is the observed noisy image and $\epsilon$ is the noise.  A popular way to remove the noise $\epsilon$ is with an algorithm called basis pursuit. To denoise with basis pursuit we choose a prior that $X$ is generate from a sparse, redundant set of visual patterns $D$ which we are given. Then to recover our original image, we split $Y$ up to into a series of patches $Y_{ij}$ and try to minimise
$$
\min_\alpha \{ ||Y_{ij} - D \alpha||^2_2 - \lambda||\alpha||_1 \}
$$
for each patch. Here $ E(x; x_0) = ||Y_{ij} - D \alpha||^2_2 $ and $R(x)= \lambda||\alpha||_1$. We could also choose different prior about what generated $X$ and this would result in a different $R(x)$.